# Why are some editions of the Blake's 7 1980 annual missing the date?

Tags: blakes-7

I am looking for information on the 1980 Blake's 7 annual. I understand that there are versions of this. One has 1980 printed on the cover and spine. The other does not, anywhere. Can anyone tell me the reason behind this. Is one a reprint? Or is the date-less annual a mistake?

Comment: Wow, if there were points for obscurity you would win them.

Answer (score 3):

It's my understanding it's a misprint in some of the run, the year was left off the cover and the inside page.

I know this because I have both editions and everything inside them (including printing details) are identical.